# Difference between a Möbius Strip and a Simple Surface

Tags: general-topology, 3d, surfaces, topological-vector-spaces

I am trying to distinguish between a Möbius strip and a surface that has no separations, holes and a connected boundary (homeomorphic to a disk or a half-sphere). Since a Möbius strip also has all the properties of a simple disk like surface, connected boundary and single side, I am finding it hard to exclude Möbius strips from the definition of a surface that I intend to focus on.

Comment: I think you want your disk to be simply connected.

Comment: How do you figure that your disk or a half-sphere has only one side?

Comment: Take a sphere $S^2$ and the Möbius strip $M$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Certainly I can colour the inner side of the surface of the sphere with a color, say green, and the outside with another, say red. But what happens if I start colouring the Möbius strip?